# When I use getopts in a Bash function, why does it ignore arguments on the second call?

Tags: bash, getopts

Below is my code

```
function waitTillGWState 
{
    if [[ $# -lt 6 ]] ; then
      echo "$FUNCNAME:: Wrong parameter specified. Exiting."
      exit 1
    fi
local Fname1
local fset
local state
local lhost

echo "$# $@"
waitTillGWState_Usage() { echo "waitTillGWState: [-F <Fname1> -t <Fname2> -S <state> -h <host>]" 1>&2; exit; }
while getopts F:t:S:h: x; do
    case ${x} in
    F)
        Fname1="${OPTARG}"
        echo "Value of Fname1 is $Fname1"
        ;;
    t)
        Fname2="${OPTARG}"
        echo "Value of Fname2 is $Fname2"
        ;;
    S)
        state="${OPTARG}"
        echo "Value of state is $state"
        ;;
    h)
        lhost="${OPTARG}"
        echo "Value of lhost is $lhost"
        ;;
    *)
       waitTillGWState_Usage
        ;;
esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "Values are  $Fname1 $Fname2 $state $lhost"

if [[ -z "${lhost}" ]] ; then
    lhost=`hostname`
fi

echo  "Values are  $Fname1 $Fname2 $state $lhost"

return 0
}
waitTillGWState -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Active
waitTillGWState -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Disconnectecd
```

Now, when i am running this, this works first time perfectly. But second time this lost the values.

```
+ waitTillGWState -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Active
+ [[ 6 -lt 6 ]]
+ local Fname1
+ local fset
+ local state
+ local lhost
+ echo '6 -F' Fname1 -t X4 -S Active
6 -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Active
+ getopts F:t:S:h: x
+ case ${x} in
+ Fname1=Fname1
+ echo 'Value of Fname1 is Fname1'
Value of Fname1 is Fname1
+ getopts F:t:S:h: x
+ case ${x} in
+ Fname2=X4
+ echo 'Value of Fname2 is X4'
Value of Fname2 is X4
+ getopts F:t:S:h: x
+ case ${x} in
+ state=Active
+ echo 'Value of state is Active'
Value of state is Active
+ getopts F:t:S:h: x
+ shift 6
+ echo 'Values are  Fname1 X4 Active '
Values are  Fname1 X4 Active
+ [[ -z '' ]]
++ hostname
+ lhost=p7fbn11
+ echo 'Values are  Fname1 X4 Active p7fbn11'
Values are  Fname1 X4 Active p7fbn11
+ return 0
+ waitTillGWState -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Disconnectecd
+ [[ 6 -lt 6 ]]
+ local Fname1
+ local fset
+ local state
+ local lhost
+ echo '6 -F' Fname1 -t X4 -S Disconnectecd
6 -F Fname1 -t X4 -S Disconnectecd
+ getopts F:t:S:h: x
+ shift 6
+ echo 'Values are   X4  '
Values are   X4
+ [[ -z '' ]]
++ hostname
+ lhost=myhost1
+ echo 'Values are   X4      myhost1'
Values are   X4  myhost1
+ return 0
```

So, i Lost values while calling 2nd time.

Any one know why is this happening?

I tried without local variable also.

Comment: Optional arguments are, as their name implies, optional. It is sometimes tempting to require an optional argument, but doing so is usually a bad idea and not just because it violates the guidelines for argument handling. Even if you decide to require optional arguments, just checking the argument count isn't a very good way of doing that. What if the user invokes `waitTillGWState -F file1 -F file2 -F file3`?

Comment: I Agree. This is taken care. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that `getopts` uses a global variable, `OPTIND`, to keep track of its progress. `OPTIND` is set to 1 when the shell starts, and is used by `getopts` to identify which argument should be parsed. Once `getopt` has scanned all the options, `OPTIND` is the index of the first positional parameter, which is why `shift $((OPTIND-1))` works.

As the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) says:

> The shell does not reset `OPTIND` automatically; it must be manually reset between multiple calls to `getopts` within the same shell invocation if a new set of parameters is to be used.